# Android: onActivityResult not getting called in tab bar activity - zxing

Tags: android, tabs, zxing

I am using a tab bar activity and I am calling a third party library (zxing) for barcode scanning using startActivityForResult but onActivityResult is not getting called after returning back from zxing library. When I used the same code in a normal activity it worked absolutely fine.

I know that the issue is because of using tab bar activity but I am not understanding how to fix this. Is there any solution for this? I tried browsing stack overflow but in vain. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: hey add your code here to find out where you are making mistake

Comment: please add your code snippet...